# 2020 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Sustainable Living's [first moderator election](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the new moderators are:

[image: L.Shaver] 
[image: Nic]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking Earthliŋ and EnergyNumbers who will be stepping down as moderators.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4932256252559360).

Comment: Congratulations LShaver & Nic! You both deserve it :)

Comment: Thanks @Robotnik!

Comment: Congratulations LShaver & Nic! @Robotnik thank you for participating in the elections. Too bad beta sites can't have 4 moderators. You contributed already quite a bit in the short time since you joined this site. I appreciate that a lot and am hoping you'll continue to do so.

Comment: @THelper - Of course! I'm here for the long haul :)

Answer (score 3):

First, I'd like to express my gratitude to all the community members who voted in this election! Thank you for trusting me to uphold the values of this community. We had pretty good participation among people who [visited the election page](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/election/1). It's great to see that our spirit of civic engagement is alive and well.

> 121 [voters] visited the election page and 67 voted.

I'd also like to say **thank you** to our outgoing moderators [Earthliŋ](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users/85/earthli%c5%8b) and [EnergyNumbers](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users/48/410-gone) who have done so much work over the past years to help develop this website into a community, and made it both a welcoming and useful site to visit.

I am very much looking forward to working with the new moderation team as [LShaver](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users/3379/LShaver) and I join up with our incumbent moderator [THelper](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users/99/thelper). I intend to continue being open and community-focused, and hope to see plenty of fruitful (and frank) community engagement here on our Meta site.

To [Robotnik](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/users/8232/robotnik) who ran alongside me in this moderator election, I want to say how much I appreciate you've been contributing to the site recently. I have noticed your contributions and believe they are very valuable to the community, and I'm glad to hear that [you're here for the long haul](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361/2020-community-moderator-election-results#comment446_361)!

Finally, I'd like to thank the community team at Stack Exchange for providing a space that makes all of this possible.